# Firebase sign out to Login Screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Wondering how to implement a complete sign out of my Firebase-enabled Android application, which will return the user to `LoginActivity`.

My Sign Out button has been implemented into an Action bar that is visible only on the `activity_main.xml`.

The code for the for the other buttons in the Action Bar is located in the `MainActivity` as a switch statement.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())

    {
        case R.id.sign_out:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //sign out
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent settings = new Intent (this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settings);
            //settings
            break;
        case R.id.emergency_contacts:
            Intent emergency_contacts = new Intent(this, EmergencyContactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(emergency_contacts);
            //emergency contacts
            break;
        default:
            //unknown error
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

At present, I have a simple Toast message, just to show that the button works.

I know this code `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`, will need to be implemented, but I'm just not sure how within a switch statement.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your toast with this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

and then fire an Intent to desired activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DesiredActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```